# Google Cloud AI platform -- VM Instance not detected as running

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-ai-platform

I have used Jupyter Notebooks through JupyterLab in GCP - AI platform for a year. I had too little memory, so I stopped the instance, resized the RAM, started the instance ( at GCP Console > Compute Engine > VM Instances). Once this was done, the OPEN JupyterLab link that is normally available at GCP Console > AI Platform > Notebooks is not clickable (see image). [image: error] I have of course restarted, reset the instance without success. I have SSH in the running machine, and restarted the Jupyter service as well

```
sudo service jupyter restart
```

It seems tha the AI platform doesn't recognize that the instance is running. Not sure about the way to go forward here.

Comment: Did you try after REFRESH the page?

Comment: Yes @Mahboob refresh, stop, reset were tested without success. Also Ctrl+F5.

Answer (score 0):

AI Notebook UI uses custom metadata keys such as proxy-mode, proxy-url, and proxy-status to determine whether or not the Open JupyterLab button should be shown. You can find this using the below gcloud command.

```
gcloud compute instances describe your-instance.
```

You can follow steps i) and ii) to re-register with Inverting Proxy Server. After that you should be able to access JupyterLab.

i) Stop and Start the VM
ii) SSH into your instance and run:

```
cd /opt/deeplearning/bin
sudo ./attempt-register-vm-on-proxy.sh
```

You can see those instructions listed in this GCP [official](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/troubleshooting#to_re-register_with_inverting_proxy_server) doc. If this doesn't work you can [migrate](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/registering-legacy-notebooks#migrate-to-new-instance) to a new AI Platform Notebooks instance.